# Detect if a checkbox is checked, then get div id

Tags: javascript

I have checkboxes on a page, when you click a span for each checkbox, it will change the background color of the containing div for each checkbox. The problem is when someone submits the form and goes to the following page, then clicks the back button the checkboxes remain checked but the div color reverts. Is there a way to get the div ids of checked boxes when the page loads?

I have this to detect checked boxes in by body onload, but not sure how to get div id for each of them:

```
function detectchecked(){
  var count = 0;
  var inputs = myform.getElementsByTagName('input');
  for (var i = 0, j = inputs.length; i<j; i++) {
      var input = inputs[i];
      if (input.type && input.type === 'checkbox' && input.checked) {
          alert(input);
      }
   }
  }
```

My current code for the inputs looks like this:

```
<div id="myform">
 <div id="div4452101" style="float:left; width:194px; height:90px; border:1px solid #000; margin:2px;"> 
  <div class="resultphoto"> 
   <span onClick="checkem('4452101');"> 
    image goes here
   </span>
  </div> 
  <span onClick="checkem('4452101');"> 
   check this
  </span> 
  <input type="checkbox" name="numbers[]" id="4452101" value="4452101" /> 
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: did you add condition if(checkbox value is there) { use this style} ?

Comment: I would suggest you to use jQuery if you are allowed to :) This would simplify the whole thing a lot..

Comment: Is the problem that it doesn't work when someone gets back to the page if browser "Back" button is pressed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need for jQuery in such a codeless and easy questions.

You must use code like this:

```
function detectchecked(){
  var count = 0;
  var inputs = myform.getElementsByTagName('input');
  for (var i = 0, j = inputs.length; i<j; i++) {
      var input = inputs[i];
      if (input.type && input.type === 'checkbox' && input.checked) {
          document.getElementById('div'+input.getAttribute('id')).setAttribute('style','Your style here');
      }
   }
  }
```

Of course, if i understood you correctly

Answer (score 1):

Did you think to use a framework ? JQuery ?

That script gonna be easy :

$('#myform input[type=checkbox]:checked').attr('style','your style');

Comment: As I stated in my comment to Bick's answer, I was able to get the id of the div with: var pid=input.parentNode.id;